# MySQL - multi join

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications

I have a table (something like)

```
product: id, name, type
product_type: id, name, group_id
product_group: id, name
```

This model is working OK, I built a query that joins tables so I can ask to get all products that has product group 14 or type 12..

Now I am facing an issue, I need to add more types to a product.

```
product: id, name, type, type_1, type_2, type_3
product_type: id, name, group_id
product_group: id, name
```

After this I have written a query that can retrieve `type=12 or type_1=12 or type_2=12` but I do not know how to write a query that will retrieve `if group=14 or group_1=14`.

My query is:

```
SELECT product.*,  
       product_group.group_name 
FROM product,
     product_group,
     product_type 
WHERE product.product_type = product_type.id 
  AND product_group.id = product_type.product_group 
  AND product_group=14
```

How can I add:

```
(... or product_group_1=14 or product_group_2=14)
```

Thank for any help, here is some example

```
- product: id=2, name=cleaning kit, type=6 (photo accessorioes), type_1=9 (video accessorioes), type_2=33 (cleaning supply)
---------------------------------
- type: id=6, name=photo accessorioes, group=12 (photo equipment)
- type: id=9, name=video accessorioes, group=14 (video equipment)
- type: id=33, name=cleaning supply, group=31 (some group)
---------------------------------
- group: id=12, name=photo equipment
- group: id=14, name=video equipment
- group: id=31, name=some group
```

Now I need to find all product that are in group 14 for example.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to rethink your model. Whenever you start naming columns _1, _2, _3 etc it's often a sign that your schema isn't normalised. What's different between the different types for a product? Could you introduce a join table like this:
product_types: product_id, type_id

EDIT
It sounds like you have many-to-many relationships (i.e. each product can have more than one group, each group can have more than one product). To achieve this in a relational DB like MySQL you need a table to join your products to your groups like this:

```
product_groups: product_id, group_id
```

You can then query for all products in a group by [JOINing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) on that table using the relevant group_id.

**EDIT**
Based on the example data you provided I would restructure your schema like this

```
product: id=2, name=cleaning kit, 
---------------------------------
product_types: product_id=2, type_id=6 
product_types: product_id=2, type_id=9
product_types: product_id=2, type_id=33
---------------------------------
type: id=6, name=photo accessorioes, group=12 (photo equipment)
type: id=9, name=video accessorioes, group=14 (video equipment)
type: id=33, name=cleaning supply, group=31 (some group)
---------------------------------
group: id=12, name=photo equipment
group: id=14, name=video equipment
group: id=31, name=some group
```

The product_types table would be a join table with a multi-column primary key on product_id and type_id. These columns are foreign keys relating to product.id and type.id respectively.

Comment: I have site that have products.
Products like (canon 500d) have their type (dslr) and group (photo equipment)
I have 3 basic pages: product page (for 500d), product_type page (for dslr) and product_group page (for photo equipment that has many types).
After adding product_type_1, product_type_2... page for product didnt change, page for product type has new query and it shows products from type, type_1, but I dont know how to do that for product group because query gets 2 complex for me to understand how to write it

Comment: ty liquorvicar for Your time, I edited main post and hoping that it could help as get solution

Comment: @day I still don't think you've quite understood. I've used the example data you provided to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, liquorvicar I understand now, this is a good solution and I will use it if it can't be done without changing model. Atm solution would be some new query if thats possible